# case when on sql

Tags: sql

what's wrong with my sql script ? It always says incorrect syntax.

```
Select Case 
When(DAY(GETDATE()) <= 23 and DAY(GETDATE()) >= 9) Then Convert(varchar(10),YEAR(getdate()))+'-'+Convert(varchar(10),MONTH(getdate()))+'-'+'9'
When(DAY(GETDATE()) <= 8 and DAY(GETDATE()) >= 24) Then  Convert(varchar(10),YEAR(getdate()))+'-'+Convert(varchar(10),MONTH(getdate()))+'-'+'24'
```

it should display 2012-11-9 or 2012-11-24 depending on the current date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you missed `end`, try this:

```
Select Case 
         When(DAY(GETDATE()) <= 23 and DAY(GETDATE()) >= 9) 
           Then Convert(varchar(10),YEAR(getdate()))+'-'+Convert(varchar(10),MONTH(getdate()))+'-'+'9'
         When(DAY(GETDATE()) <= 8 and DAY(GETDATE()) >= 24) 
           Then  Convert(varchar(10),YEAR(getdate()))+'-'+Convert(varchar(10),MONTH(getdate()))+'-'+'24'
       end as Date1
from YourTable
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to `End` your Case

```
Select Case 
    When(DAY(GETDATE()) <= 23 and DAY(GETDATE()) >= 9) Then Convert(varchar(10),YEAR(getdate()))+'-'+Convert(varchar(10),MONTH(getdate()))+'-'+'9'
    When(DAY(GETDATE()) <= 8 and DAY(GETDATE()) >= 24) Then  Convert(varchar(10),YEAR(getdate()))+'-'+Convert(varchar(10),MONTH(getdate()))+'-'+'24'
End
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the missing `end`, one of your `case` conditions is never going to be true

```
When(DAY(GETDATE()) <= 8 and DAY(GETDATE()) >= 24)
```

use

```
   case when DAY(GETDATE()) between 9 and 23 then CONVERT(varchar(8),getdate(),120) + '9'
        else CONVERT(varchar(8),getdate(),120) + '24'
   end
```

Also, your logic looks potentially suspect. Do you really want to return 24th October for both the 2nd of October and the 30th?